# print first row of a 2d Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have the below code and I'm attempting to print out only the first row of this 2d array

```
# how many columns
for (my $c = 0; $c <= $#list[0]; $c++) {
print $list[0][$c]."\n";
```

the data should be something like

```
[0] => "ID,Cluster,Version"
[1] => "2,32,v44"
```

The Error:

```
syntax error at ./connect_qb.pl line 107, near "$#list["
syntax error at ./connect_qb.pl line 107, near "++) "
Execution of ./connect_qb.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$list[0]
```

is a reference to an array, so the array is

```
@{ $list[0] }
```

so the last element of that array is

```
$#{ $list[0] }
```

so you'd use

```
for my $c (0 .. $#{ $list[0] }) {
   print "$list[0][$c]\n";
}
```

or

```
for (@{ $list[0] }) {
   print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid c-style for loops. Here's one way to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @a = (["ID","Cluster","Version"], ["2","32","v44"]);
say for (@{$a[0]});
```

A slightly less confusing dereferencing:

```
...
my $ref = $a[0];
say for (@$ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one liner for that

```
print join(",",@{$list[0]}),"\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (my $c = 0; $c <=  (scalar @{$list[0]}); $c++)
```

for the loop condition